# Select MAX value and cast

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting, max

I have a table with the following columns:

```
[Id]
[fk_Player_Id]
[fk_Innings_Id]
[Minutes]
[Balls]
[Runs]
[fk_HowOut_Id]
[fk_Bowler_Id]
```

I need a query that returns the record with the maximum runs but based on the fk_HowOut_Id value for the row i might need to add an asterisk to the value.

I have tried this query -

```
SELECT Player.LastName + ' ' + LEFT(player.FirstName, 1) as PlayerName,COUNT(DISTINCT match.MatchId) AS Matches, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id != 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Innings',
COUNT(CASE WHEN BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Not Outs',
SUM(BatInnings.Runs) AS 'Aggregate',
CASE WHEN (COUNT(CASE WHEN BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id != 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) - COUNT(CASE WHEN BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) > 0 THEN SUM(BatInnings.Runs) / (COUNT(CASE WHEN BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id != 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) - COUNT(CASE WHEN BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) ELSE 0 END AS 'Average',
CAST(MAX(BatInnings.Runs) AS varchar(3)) + CASE WHEN BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 THEN '*' 
                                                                                 ELSE ''
                                                                                 END AS 'High Score'
FROM Match
JOIN Innings ON Innings.fk_Match_Id = Match.MatchId
JOIN BatInnings ON BatInnings.fk_Innings_Id = Innings.Id
Join Player On player.Id = BatInnings.fk_Player_Id
WHERE Player.ClubId = 1088
group by Player.id, player.FirstName, player.LastName
Order by PlayerName
```

and i get an error message returned of:

```
Column 'BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Can i get pointed in the right direction.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you post the full query

Comment: The error message says it load and clear - you are using fk_HowOut_Id in the select clause of a group by query but it's not a part of the group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the query working with with this query

```
(Select CAST(t.Runs as varchar(3)) + CASE WHEN t.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 Then '*' ELSE '' End FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM BatInnings b WHERE b.fk_Player_Id = P.Id Order By b.Runs DESC) t) AS 'High Score'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the context of the query, I think you forgot a `count()` around your `case` statement in the last item in your select. That puts it outside of an aggregate function in the select, which would cause the error you are seeing:

```
    ...
MAX(BatInnings.Runs) AS varchar(3)) + CASE WHEN 
    sum(case when BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 then 1 else 0 end)>0
  THEN '*' ELSE ''END) AS 'High Score'
    ...
```

Comment: I have just tried that and that seems to adding one run to the players total runs, not adding an asterix to the end of the Batting.Runs.  Unles i am missing something obvious.

Comment: I'm not sure what this column is supposed to represent...I don't know anything at all about baseball statistics. But you probably need an aggregate function somewhere around the `BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id`, but I can't say where. Maybe it should be `CASE WHEN count(BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id = 7)>0`, or maybe it should be `CASE WHEN count(BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id) = 7`...or maybe the `count` should be a `sum`.

Comment: Its actually cricket stats. :)  I will try to explain what the outcome should be..  The table BatInnings stores each batters innings stats.  I want to get the highest score for each batter.  But on top of that, i want to add an identifier to signal if the batter was not out during that innings.  The fk_HowOut_id is a foreign key to a Dismissals table there the id of 7 is "Not Out".  So if a better scores 64 runs and is not out then i would like it to display '64*'

Comment: Oops, guess I don't know much about cricket either :-). I have modified my answer above to reflect what I think you're saying. The query above will add the star if any of the BatInnings shows a HowOut of 7. However it is possible that you might want to add the star only if **all** of the HowOut values are 7? If that's the case, there are a couple of ways you can do it. The easiest would be to look for `sum(case when BatInnings.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 then 0 else 1 end)=0`

Comment: So close.  That is putting a star next to the score if the batter has ever had a not out, as opposed to that actual score being not out...

Comment: That's an issue with your group by. Each row in your results is not a single "at bat," but a summary of all results for a given `Player.id, player.FirstName, player.LastName`.

Comment: I have nutted out this query which returns the the score in the output that is required.  I just can't seem to to select the record for the particular batter.  It is returning all of the batters..  Ideas on how to integrate this in?
`(SELECT CAST(t.Runs as varchar(3)) + CASE WHEN t.fk_HowOut_Id = 7 THEN '*' ELSE '' END AS 'High Score' FROM (SELECT a.fk_Player_Id, a.Runs, a.fk_HowOut_Id FROM BatInnings a
     
     INNER JOIN (
      SELECT fk_player_id, MAX(Runs) runs
      FROM BatInnings
      
      GROUP BY fk_Player_Id) b ON      a.fk_Player_Id = b.fk_Player_Id AND a.runs = b.runs) t)`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help without more information. We've gone from resolving a particular error message (I believe we've resolved that issue), and now we are talking about changing the basic structure of the results. Your original query groups information into a single row per player, and now it sounds like you are wanting the data grouped differently than that. But I'm not sure how. I can't help you change the data structure without understanding what it ought to be. Might be best to do that by either editing your question or posting a new question...it's a bit much for comments section.